# Rails - document.ready not working in specific JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

A piece of JavaScript I wrote (which lives in app/assets/javascripts/tenant_content.js) wasn't working so I boiled it down to the following in order to test it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Test");
});
```

When I refresh the page nothing is logged to the console.

If I remove the `console.log` from within the `document.ready` then it prints just fine. The strange thing is it also works if I move it to one of my other JavaScript files. It seems to be the combination of being in this particular file and being within the `document.ready` function that causes it not to work. Any ideas why?

Note: I'm not using Turbolinks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an error in a different JavaScript file that was stopping the rest of the JavaScript from running. The reason it was specific to one file was because it was the only file that came after the error file in the tree:

```
javascripts
  counter.js
  notices.js
  stripe.js                << this is where the error occurred...
  tenant_content.js        << ...so the JS in this file wasn't running
```

I hadn't realised that anything after the error wouldn't run.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you've removed it, you will by default have Turbolinks running.

Instead of doing a full page load when you click links, it'll be doing XHR requests and replacing the `body` using javascript.

Because of this, you don't experience any `document.ready` events. Instead you should be using one of these, depending on which version you are running:

```
$(document).ready(myFunc); // What you're currently doing, but isn't working
$(document).on('page:load', myFunc); // Classic Turbolinks (Rails 4)
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', myFunc); // Turbolinks 5 (Rails 5)
```

Comment: I actually have fully removed Turbolinks. I figured it out in the end, check my answer if you're curious as to what the issue was. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using Rails 6.

Answer (score 0):

This means that `document.ready` fired before this event was binded. So your DOM is ready before script is loaded.

If this tag is at the bottom of page, put it up. Or remove `asynch` and `deferred` attributes.

Comment: It was actually an error that was preventing it from firing, I didn't realise that it would stop the rest of the JS from running. Thanks for your answer though!